# System Could not boot from harddisk after installing ubuntu

Tags: boot, windows, bootloader

I need some help here, i wanted to install Ubuntu on my laptop which have a 1TB storage and only 1 partition(C:) running windows 8.1, so i burnt the ISO file for Ubuntu to a USB device and I installed it form there, when an option for choosing my installation type appears i choose some thing else and then, i made a new partition from the existing one big partition and gave it a size of 300GB, then i proceeded to the installation assuming that all my very critical work files on the windows 8.1 secion will be fine, after the installation is successfully done, my pc keeps on booting from the USB drive, when i remove the usb drive i get an error that says "No boot device connected", i tried to install  Boot repair being on try ubuntu option but it is not helping, please please i need your help, i have hundruds of thousands of lines of code on my other partaion, is there any way i could get both my windows and ubuntu working, or at least windows, please?

Answer (score 0):

Open your **Terminal** from Ubuntu and hit `sudo update-grub` This command fix your bootloader.

Answer (score 0):

Boot the Windows recovery CD and repair your partition.

If you want to get Ubuntu back,  boot the Ubuntu live and run a `sudo grub-install /dev/sdX` where x is the *drive* you want to have the boot menu